# Выключение wi-fi на устройстве Android

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Хочу сделать чтоб зайдя в мое приложение у пользователя отключался wi-fi, или просто отключение от сети.

Это возможно вообще? Буду благодарен за информацию.
И где можно почитать про манипуляции с устройством через приложение?

Comment: Если вы хотите, чтобы ваше приложение ни при каких условиях даже с пинка пользователя не работало с выключенным вайфаем, то скорее всего никак. Система может заставить приложение поверить во многие странные вещи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Вбиваем в гугл

> android turn off wifi programmatically

2. Идём по первой ссылке на [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8863540/3212712)
3. Получаем ответ:

Нужны следующие разрешения в манифесте:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Для включения/выключения Wi-Fi можно использовать этот код (в классе активити):

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
```

А вот так там же можно проверить включён он или нет:

```
boolean wifiEnabled = wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()
```

Comment: Ну не учат они этот английский чтобы нормально серфить по поисковикам..(

Comment: @KryTer_NexT, возможно также, дело в неумении сформировать релевантный запрос) Или вбивают в яндекс - он плохо такие запросы обрабатывает.